# How to return data from python script

Tags: python, output

I have this code within a python script that returns to following output

```
dir = ["/var/www", "/usr/share"]
for dir_name in dirs:
        if os.path.exists(dir_name):
            cmd = ["drush", "st"]
            rc, out, err = module.run_command(cmd, cwd=dir_name)
            if rc == 0:
                info = out.splitlines()
                version = info[0].strip().split(':')[-1].strip()
                return {'version':  version}
```

output:

```
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                :  Linux
 Drush version         :  6.2.0
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :
```

How do I get the version 6.2.0 returned by the version variable?

Comment: use a regex maybe, either in python, or a grep utility?

Comment: i am confused, the code looks exactly to return the version. what's your question?  `version = info[0].strip().split(':')[-1].strip()`

Comment: Do you mean from an external program or within the python script?

Comment: Yes its ansible. The script is returning the following "drupal": {
        "version": "/usr/bin/php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do something like this?

```
version.partition('version')[2].split('\n')[0].split(':')[1].strip()
```

I took the liberty of considering

```
version = '''PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php
PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
PHP OS                :  Linux
Drush version         :  6.2.0
Drush configuration   :
Drush alias files     : '''
```

This should work however it is better to use regex.